# Pushing Python introspection to limits

Tags: python, reflection, introspection

Simple question – can I print the source code of this `if`?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # ...
  # this is the `if` I want to print
  #  V 
  if args and args[0][0] == '-':
    if args[0] in ('--help','-h','-?'):
      print_source_of_block(level=2)
    icase = 'i' in args[0]
    desc = 'd' in args[0]
    args = args[1:]
```

Please don't ask me why I need it, nor give me advice on how to write user help. I want to know it because I'm curious.

Comment: I don't ask why you need this but here are some essential questions. You have this snippet in a file or a function? Is it part of an object or not? have you searched about it so far? what have you tried and whats the problem with your code?

Comment: Sorry to be so rude, but I haven't done any research and I don't plan on doing any. Neither do I expect anyone to do research for me. Rather I just ask in case someone knows the answer. If no one knows, it's not a problem. It's not vital for me to know the answer to this question and neither do I have time to look for an answer on my own in other way than simply asking on stackoverflow. In other cases I would take an effort, but I suspect this will not even be possible and hence I don't want to waste time on it.

Comment: Well that's ok, but you need to be clear enough in your question if you expect a correct and comprehensive answer and that's why my first question was about your code. Also I think searching in google and just reading would be so faster than asking a question and waiting for the sun to shine ;-). Nevertheless, if you just want to know if it's possible or not the answer is yes. Because  based on *Von Neumann*’s model of a “stored program computer,” code is also represented by objects. And accessing to objects in python is usually so easy.

Comment: You're implying it's "so easy" to do what I want? Then show me :D

Comment: It's like giving someone a fish or teaching him/her the fishing. Unfortunately I'm not the one who gives you the fish, maybe if your question was a trivial one I'd do that but this is an interesting question and doesn't come in everybody's mind easily, and that's why I think the questioner deserves more than just a simple answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's doable. Here's a quick sketch of how you could do it and what tools would be involved:

1. Retrieve the stack frame of `print_source_of_block`'s caller with [`inspect.currentframe().f_back`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe).
2. Determine the caller's source file and line number within that source file with [`inspect.getframeinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getframeinfo).
3. Open the source file.
4. Either

   - Use [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) to parse the file, or
   - Use [`tokenize.tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.tokenize) to tokenize it.
5. Using either the abstract syntax tree or the token stream, determine where the requested source block begins and ends.
6. Print the block.

Comment: I kind of hoped I could avoid steps 4 and 5, but I guess that wasn't a very realistic expectation.

Answer (score 2):

Might want to look at the `inspect` module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html).  Specifically, the `inspect.getsource(object)` method.

Comment: I figure I could use a hack based on Python's indentation-defined block syntax. No actual parsing necessary.

Comment: @kyrill: That's *almost* what the tokenization-based solution would be, except that you can also have things like one-liner `if`s, which do not involve `INDENT` and `DEDENT` tokens in the token stream. It's much harder to get those right, hard enough to make the AST solution preferable.